# Матрица с fstream. Найти максимум среди отрицательных и минимум среди положительных элементов

Tags: файлы, матрицы, c++

Составить программу нахождения максимального элемента среди отрицательных чисел и минимального элемента среди положительных для каждой строки матрицы.

```
//пример:    
//-1 2 3 min 2 max -1
//4 -5 6 min 4 max -5
//7 8 9 min 7 max нет

 #include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void FileOpen(fstream &f, char *fname, ios_base::openmode mode);
void FileRead(fstream &f, int &N, int &M, int **&a);
void CountData(int &N, int &M, int **&a, int *&arMin, int *&arMax);
void FileClose(fstream &f);
void FileOut(fstream &f, int &N, int &M, int **&a, int *&arMin, int *&arMax);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    fstream fin, fout;
    FileOpen(fin, "in.txt", ios::in);
    int N;
    int M;
    int **a;
    FileRead(fin, N, M, a);
    int *arMin;
    arMin = new int[N];
    int *arMax;
    arMax = new int[N];
    CountData(N, M, a, arMin, arMax);
    FileClose(fin);
    FileOpen(fout, "out.txt", ios::out);
    FileOut(fout, N, M, a, arMin, arMax);
    FileClose(fout);
    return 0;
}

void FileOpen(fstream &f, char *fname, ios_base::openmode mode)
{
    f.open(fname, mode);
    if (!f)
    {
        cout << "Ошибка 1: Файла " << fname << " нет на диске" << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void FileClose(fstream &f)
{
    f.close();
}

void FileRead(fstream &f, int &N, int &M, int **&a)
{
    f >> ws;
    f.ignore(4, '=');
    f>> N;
    if (N <= 0 || !f)
    {
        cout << "Ошибка 2: Ошибка ввода строк матрицы";
        system("pause");
        exit(2);
    }
    f >> ws;
    f.ignore(4, '=');
    f >> M;
    if (M <= 0 || !f)
    {
        cout << "Ошибка 3: Ошибка ввода столбцов матрицы";
        system("pause");
        exit(3);
    }
    a = new int *[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        a[i] = new int[M];
    }
    f >> ws;
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<M; j++)
        {
            f >> a[i][j];
            if (!f)
            {
                cout << "Ошибка 4: Ошибка ввода элементов";
                system("pause");
                exit(4);
            }
        }
    }
}

void FileOut(fstream &f, int &N, int &M, int **&a, int *&arMin, int *&arMax)
{
    f << "Составить программу нахождения максимального элемента среди отрицательных " << endl;
    f << "и минимального элемента среди положительных для каждой строки матрицы.";
    f << endl << endl << "Данная матрица: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<M; j++)
        {
            f << a[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        f << endl;
    }
    f << endl;
    f << "Решение задачи: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        if (arMin[i] == 1000)   f << "Минимальный положительный элемент " << i + 1 << " строки отсутствует" << endl;
        else f << "Минимальный положительный элемент " << i + 1 << " строки: " << arMin[i] << endl;
        if (arMax[i] == -1000) f << "Максимальный отрицательный элемент " << i + 1 << " строки отсутствует" << endl;
        else f << "Максимальный отрицательный элемент " << i + 1 << " строки:" << arMax[i] << endl;
        f << endl;
    }

}

void CountData(int &N, int &M, int **&a, int *&arMin, int *&arMax)
{
    int max = -1000;
    int min = 1000;

    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<M; j++)
        {
            if ((a[i][j]>max) && (a[i][j]<0)) max = a[i][j];
            if ((a[i][j]<min) && (a[i][j]>0)) min = a[i][j];
        }
        arMax[i] = max;
        arMin[i] = min;
        max = -1000;
        min = 1000;
    }

}
```

у меня вопрос. как min и max найти без константы? (-1000 и 1000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если возвращать не сами max/min для строк, а их индексы

(а ведь Вам все равно нужно отличать отсутствие min/max от экстемальных значений),

то можно так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  arMax[i] = arMin[i] = -1;
  for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
    if (a[i][j] < 0) {
      if (arMax[i] == -1 || a[i][j] > max) {
        max = a[i][j];
        arMax[i] = j;
      }
    }
    if (a[i][j] > 0) {
      if (arMin[i] == -1 || a[i][j] < min) {
        min = a[i][j];
        arMin[i] = j;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Верный подход. Также можно возвращать указатель за последний элемент (аналог `-1`), если работать используя итераторы и стандартные алгоритмы.

Answer (score 0):

По-всякому. Например, возьмите максимальное/минимальное значение типа `int`. Или заведите флаги, показывающие, встретился вам уже отрицательный/положительный элемент в текущей строке или нет.

Comment: Ну вот например :
int max;
int min;
 
 for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
 {
 max = A[i][0];
 min = A[i][0];
 for (int j = 1; j<M; j++)
 {
 if ((a[i][j]>max) && (a[i][j]<0)) max = a[i][j];
 if ((a[i][j]<min) && (a[i][j]>0)) min = a[i][j];
 }
 arMax[i] = max;
 arMin[i] = min;
 }

Как его вынести в этот цикл?

Comment: @DZPG: Не-не, вы не можете воспользоваться нулевым элементом, он же может быть неположительным. Ну или неотрицательным.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/